# Front Porch Pavers near Threshold Level

Tags: porch, pavers

I got a bunch of pavers a few months back thinking I would have the time to pave my porch. Now that I finally started getting the rest of the stuff together, I am realizing that they are a bit close to the threshold. I live in Florida, so rain runoff is a real consideration that I did not consider when thinking about doing this overlay. As a bonus, my porch is near dead level (no 1/4-1/8" per foot slope), so that would have me raising the pavers near the house at least another half inch with a concrete overlay in order to correct the slope.

Is it safe to do so leaving only ~1" between the pavers and threshold, or should I find some other project to use these 2.5 pallets of pavers for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the 2nd picture showing us?

Comment: @FreeMan Sorry, that's showing the height of the foundation before the siding starts

Comment: You could rent a concrete saw and cut properly angled grooves into the concrete surface to run water out from underneath the pavers, rather than build it up: assuming it's not absurdly thin. There is not a porch roof, I assume? Or is there?

Comment: @Ecnerwal There is a roof, but my house is on the rundown to the Bayou, so rain runoff is bound to happen even when I finish the dry creek I have planned.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a rainy climate.  Building code here specs a minimum of 4" drop from the top of the impermeable sill water proofing to the top surface of your exterior impermeable surface.  Your sill fascia looks like a 1x4 so you've got the 4" drop.

What we often do here to have a better look is to build on top of the impermeable level with a permeable product.  In your case I'd go with composite decking on top of pressure treated sleepers on top of the concrete.

Comment: I may well be wrong, but if those pavers are laid down and contained from the outside (maybe steel edging holding them in place) but _without_ sand/etc. between them, wouldn't water run through the pavers and down to the existing concrete and satisfy the requirement? It wouldn't be _as_ permeable as your recommendation, but would allow the OP to work with what he purchased and probably can no longer return.

Comment: It could work.  Not as much air space for any water to dissipate.  Just depends on how much that metal edging would cost.

Comment: Plan was to use landscape glue to hold down the perimeter with no edging (basically just sitting atop the concrete porch)

Comment: do you have to worry about frost or does it never freeze/snow?

Comment: rarely, gets below freezing maybe a few days a year.  Snows once every 3-5 years for a day